# C++ linker missing library when running (SONAME behavior)

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared

I've made a program that uses two shared libraries (which I compiled) and are placed like this:

```
/home_directory_where_I_compile_and_run_everything
-->/lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so
-->/lib/libre2.so.0
```

When I compile my program I pass the relative location of those libraries to the linker, like this:

```
g++ ...... stuff ........ my_program.cc lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so lib/libre2.so.0
```

And it compiles fine, however when running the program it fails to find libre2.so, and if I inspect it with ldd, here's what happens:

```
....
lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so (0x00007f62906bc000)
libre2.so.0 => not found
....
```

Apparently, it does acknowledge that the path on libjson is relative, but it doesn't do that on libre2.so.0 (it trims all the path and just leaves libre2.so.0)

Can someone tell me why this happens?

Also, is there a way to modify this via a g++ argument?

Best.

*** UPDATE *** Whoa check this out!
I've changed the name of libre2.so.0 to stuff.so, and then tried to compile essentially the same like this:

```
g++ ...... stuff ........ my_program.cc lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so lib/stuff.so
```

And it fails anyways; not only it does fail, it fails because it can't find "libre2.so.0".

Whyyy?

*** UPDATE # 2 ***

Output for `readelf -d the_program.o`

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libre2.so.0]
```

Now, if I could just make that [libre2.so.0] to be [lib/libre2.so.0] instead it would be fine.

*** UPDATE # 3 ***

As @troubadour found out:

> When an executable is linked with a shared object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the linker.

That's why it works with libjson.....so and not with libre2.so.0. (libjson.....so does not have an entry for SONAME).

And I finally found the exact question for what I'm looking for:

**Is there any way to tell the gcc linker to ignore the SONAME entries on a shared library file and link instead to the specific file path?**

Comment: Run ldconfig to update the cache and then it should work.

Comment: Is the current directory in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? In fact, can you edit your question to show us what is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Also, I assume the libraries are _not_ being built with any `-rpath` or `-runpath` options?

Comment: Ok, I've ran ldconfig and nothing changed. Also, here's my LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<empty>.

Comment: Sorry I've assumed those libraries are in the standard places since it found the first one.  Edit /etc/ld.so.conf and add your library path into it, then run ldconfig again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll answer the second part of your question first i.e. why renaming libre2.so.0 didn't do what you expected.

The file name that you pass to the linker is irrelevant when you run the executable (unless you fail to supply `-soname` when building the library - see second edit below). The dependency is taken from what is called the "soname". If you run the `readelf` command on your library you can determine its soname eg.

```
readelf -d libre2.so.0 | grep SONAME
```

It doesn't matter if you rename the file. The result of the above command will still give you the same soname, hence the reason the program still failed to find "libre2.so.0".

As to the original part of your question it all hinges on whether the libraries have an `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` built in to them and/or what the content of your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is. These are the things the run-time linker (ld.so) will use to find the shared libraries. Try

```
man ld.so
```

for more information.

Since you built the libraries yourself you will know whether or not they used the `-rpath` or `-runpath` options at the final linking stage. Alternatively, use `readelf` again eg.

```
readelf -d libre2.so.0 | grep RPATH
readelf -d libre2.so.0 | grep RUNPATH
```

I suspect the above two commands will return nothing.

My guess was going to be that you have the current directory in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which would allow the run-time linker to find lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so but not libre2.so.0. I notice that you've replied to my comment on your question to say that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty. That's odd.

Perhaps you've somehow got the prefix "lib/" on the soname for libjson? i.e. did the `readelf` command for the SONAME return

```
lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so
```

rather than just

```
libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so
```

Also, check what the program needs in terms of soname by running

```
readelf -d my_progam | grep NEEDED
```

Perhaps the "lib/" prefix is in there because of the way you passed it to gcc. If so then if you use the gcc command given by @enobayram then it will level the playing field i.e. it will fail to find libjson too.

The first thing to establish is not why it is *not* finding libre2.so.0 but how it *is* managing to find libjson. If you try running your executable from a different directory does it still work or does it now fail for libjson too? Alternatively, if you copy libre2.so.0 to be beside your executable does that change anything?

**Edit**

A [posting on the Fedora Forum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=262936) suggest that the Fedora version of ld.so has the current directory as a built-in search path. I haven't been able to verify this though but it would explain why you are picking up any libraries at all given that all the other things ld.so uses are absent on your case.

**Edit 2**

From the ld man page on my system

> -soname=name
>
> When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_SONAME field
>   to the specified name.  When an executable is linked with a shared
>   object which has a DT_SONAME field, then when the executable is run
>   the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object specified by
>   the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the
>   linker.
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999,
>   2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009 Free
>   Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document
>   under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.3 or
>   any later version published by the Free Software Foundation; with no
>   Invariant Sections, with no Front-Cover Texts, and with no Back- Cover
>   Texts.  A copy of the license is included in the section entitled "GNU
>   Free Documentation License".

So, the theory in your comment is correct. If no `-soname` is explicitly specified when the library is built then no SONAME exists in the shared object and the NEEDED field in the executable simply has the file name given to the linker which, in your case, contained the leading "lib/".

Comment: Ok so, readelf shows nothing on RPATH neither RUNPATH for both libre2.so and libjson....so. I've noticed that libjson......so does not have an entry for SONAME. And also if I move the file to another directory and execute it, it's not able to find any of both libraries.

Comment: Here's a 'theory', the linker is not able to find a SONAME for libjson....so so it 'imprints' the full path into the library reference, and then, since libre2.so.0 has a SONAME it does something like "well this dude SHOULD have installed libre2.so.0 in any of the standard locations" and just puts the name of the library in there.

Comment: @almosnow: Thanks for trying that. I've added another bit to my answer. Try the `readelf`  command on your executable that searches for `NEEDED`. I'm hoping that produces the extra "lib/" we're looking for.

Comment: For "pretty-print", I've updated my question with the output for that.

Comment: @almosnow: Okay that explains where the extra "lib/" comes from. However I'm still not sure why the run-time linker is searching relative to the executable. If your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is truly empty (i.e. does not contain even just a single dot) then the only thing left is /etc/ld.so.conf. Does it contain a line with just a dot on it?

Comment: Nope :c, it doesn't, there's also nothing in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.

Comment: That's nice, thanks so far. Now, is there a way to explicity tell the linker to link against the file, as if no SONAME exists in the library? So far, I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Comment: @almosnow: You can use the `-rpath` option to the linker when you create the executable to essentially tell it to "bake" the path into the executable. You can check that it gets in by running `readelf` again and this time grep'ing for RPATH.

Answer (score 3):

When you link against shared libraries (.so), these must exist in your library load path when you *execute* the program. The location you provided upon link time is not "remembered" in the executable.

Alternative solutions:

- place the .so files in the same directory as the executable
- run with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib ./program`
- install the .so files to a location in the library path, for example `/usr/local/lib`, before you run the program.
- link statically

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If that's true, how come it does work with libjson.....so ? Best.

Comment: Hard to tell, maybe libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so is found somewhere else on your system? ld.so works in mysterious ways...

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` as @MattH suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You need tell where the shared library is in two situations.

**One is at linking time**.
There are several ways:

- copy library to some standard directory, like `/usr/local/lib`, and install it
  via `ldconfig`. In this way, no other option/operation is needed.
- use `-L` to tell gcc where to find the lib

**One is at running time**.
Also several ways:

- like linking time, install it via `ldconfig`, then no other action needed.
- using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

  > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./a.out
- using `rpath` to write searching path into executable

  > g++ main.cpp -lxxx -L/a/b/c -Wl,-rpath,/a/b/c

Only specifying shared library location in the linking phase, for example via `-L`, does not mean when you run the program the system's loader will find the needed library.

Answer (score 0):

The correct compiler command line should be:

```
g++ ...... stuff ........ my_program.cc -Llib -ljson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt -lre2
```

And you should either put the shared objects in a standard directory (like /usr/lib) or you should add their path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be able to run your executable.

Comment: I mean that's a way you could do it, but it's not answering my question, but thanks anyway :D

Comment: Well, if you insist on getting the wrong way (in my opinion) to work. I'm also interested in knowing why it "works" with libjson though.

Comment: Yeah, that will definitely shed some light (at least for me) onto how the linker really works.

Comment: I believe what causes the difference is the fact that what you link as libjson is in fact a symbolic link. Maybe the linker has to remember the full path so that the symbolic link points to the right relative place? (speculation). (This is still the wrong way)

Comment: libjson is not a symbolic link. Moved to a fresh and clean minimal installation of Fedora and tried again, everything is still the same.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if a .so file isn't a symbolic link. Did you check this using `ls -l lib/libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so`?

Comment: Here it is: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 362558 Apr 17 21:59 libjson_linux-gcc-4.4.6_libmt.so

Comment: OK, that's strange. I'm also unable to reproduce this situation, so I'm out of ideas (speculation).